# How does breezejs's EntityManager work?

Tags: javascript, breeze

I've read the breeze.js's documentation (great documentation, by the way), but I have a doubt about the EntityManager.

Suppose I have the following factory method:

```
  var createManager = function () {
        return new breeze.EntityManager({
            serviceName: serviceName,
            metadataStore: store
        });
    };
```

Then I define two instances of Entitymanager:

```
em1 = createManager();
em2 = createManager();
```

If a call

```
em1.saveChanges();
```

Does `em2` save changes too?

Do `em1` and `em2` share the same cache?

If not, do I have to make a Singleton EntityManager? In my project, I access EntityManager in many places, exchange entities among them, so I am not sure what is the best (or correct) architecture to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the entity manager acts as its own data context on the client. When you create em1 and em2, you are creating 2 different managers, so they save independently of each other. If you want to refer to the same entitymanager in multiple places (which is one of its virtues) you can use the javascript module pattern to reference the instance you create.

My preferred technique is to create a module called datacontext. It owns the entity manager and any other custom features I want surrounding breeze. All other modules reference this datacontext and just ask it for data. The datacontext hides breeze from the rest of the modules. Its not the only way, but I like it because it follows good separation patterns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you John! I'll follow your advice. As you say, "Separate the Ravioli"!

Comment: You are correct, John. The two managers are independent and have their own cache. What they share is (a) the talk to the same service and (b) they share the same metadataStore.

Sharing the store means only one trip to the server for metadata (which ever em does it first).

Separate managers are useful when isolating changes, e.g., "sandbox" editing of a Customer in em1; its changes won't be visible to a UI bound to entities in em2. That's a topic for another day.

Comment: @BernardoPacheco - I overlooked your intent. John's suggestion is a good one. Many apps - perhaps yours - only need a single manager. Put that manager where every ViewModel can find it using a module pattern. Better yet, do as John suggests and encapsulate that manager in a "datacontext" module ... and make that module available to the other modules that need it. John has good examples of modularity in his Pluralsight courses.

Comment: @Ward - Great point! Separate managers like "sandbox" may be useful. I have already separate in a datacontext module, everything is ok. John's pluralsight courses are excellent. Thanks again! -

Comment: Documentation about John Papa and Ward said: Separate the EntityManager in a datacontext [link](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/share-entitymanager). Multiple EntityManagers, sandbox [link](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/multiple-managers)